# XMLHttpRequest POST response via JSON always null (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

after scanning through several threads here I am still stuck on this one. 
I am currently creating my 1st chrome extension and try to get user information from my REST service. It looks like this:

```
private function getUserInformation(){
  // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
  if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
    $this->response('',406);
  }
  $userkey = $this->_request['userkey'];
  $status = $this->_request['status'];

  if(!empty($userkey) and !empty($status)){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_userkey = '$userkey' AND status = '$status' ", $this->db);
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
      $result = array();

      while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $result = $rlt;
      }

      // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and return list of users in JSON format
      $this->response($this->json($result), 200);

    }
  }
  $this->response('',204);  // If no records "No Content" status
}
```

Now I want to send a userkey and status from my extension and receive the respective information out of the DB.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST",'http://myHomepage/getUserInformation/',true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText || null);
              console.log("res: " + res.name);
          }
  }

  xhr.send("userkey=123thb&status=v");
```

This gives me always "null" within the console. 
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: And what is the content of `xhr.responseText`? Is it null/undefined as well? Also there's should be `return` after the `$this->response($this->json($result), 200);` line because `$this->response('',204);` is always sending as a response.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally found the error.
Had to set the header information of the XMLHttpRequest in order to POST variables correctly.

Here is the running code:

```js
//check if userkey is in DB
  var res = callUrl('POST', 'http://example/rest/getUserInformation/', 'userkey=123thb&status=v', function ausgabe(res){
     // + userkey  + '&status=v/', function ausgabe(res){
    if (res !== null){
      console.log("userkey: " + res.user_userkey);
    }else{
      console.log("der userkey nicht gefunden for user: " + userkey);
    }
  });
```

Note that I put the XMLHttpRequest now into a function which looks like this:

```js
function callUrl(type, url, parms, callback){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(type, url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText || null);
              callback(res);

          }
  }

  xhr.send(parms);
}
```

And here is the REST php code:

```
private function getUserInformation(){
  // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
  if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
    $this->response('',406);
  }
  $userkey = $this->_request['userkey'];
  $status = $this->_request['status'];

  if(!empty($userkey) and !empty($status)){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_userkey = '$userkey' AND status = '$status' ", $this->db);
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
      $result = array();

      while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $result = $rlt;
      }

      // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and return list of users in JSON format
      $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
      return;

    }
  }
  $this->response('',204);  // If no records "No Content" status
}
```

Also I added these lines to the top of my PHP rest service:

```html
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Might not be safe but is only for a quick prototype in my case.